# How to query another entity in entity class in symfony2 using doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to query using entity manager in a entity class file but I'm getting this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Acme\MasoudBundle\Entity\User::getDoctrine() in /var/www/test/src/Acme/MasoudBundle/Entity/User.php line 192
```

my entity class is :

```
namespace Acme\MasoudBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
{
     /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
     public function setEmail($email)
     {
         $this->email = $email;

         return $this;
     }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActive
     *
     * @param boolean $isActive
     * @return User
     */
    public function setIsActive($isActive)
    {
        $this->isActive = $isActive;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActive
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getIsActive()
    {
        return $this->isActive;
    }
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $Permission= $em->getRepository('MasoudBundle:Permission')->find(1);
        $this->permissions[]=$Permission->permission;
        return $this->permissions;
    }
}
```

I want to have a permission and authentication system like this, can you help me please? there are 5 tables, a user table, a group table, a permission table, and a group_permission and a user_group table. so After user logins, I want to check which user is for which group, and get the groups permission. how can I do that? please help me as much as you have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entity should not know about other entities and the [Entity Manager](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php) because of the [separation of concerns](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/49/what-is-symfony2).

Why don't you simply map your `User` to the appropriate Role(s) (instances of `Permission` entity in your case) using [Doctrine Entity Relationships/Associations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#entity-relationships-associations). It will allow you to access the appropriate permissions of a given user from the `User` instance itself.

Comment: I want to have a system like this, can you help me please? there are 5 tables, a user table, a group table, a permission table, and a group permission and a user group table. so After user logins, I want to check which user is for which group, and get the groups permission. how can I do that? please help me.

Comment: This is the way to go. Why write your own relations if doctrine supports most kinds very well?

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

`$this` refers to the current class, the `User Entity` that does not have a method called `getDoctrine()`. `$this->getDoctrine()` works in controllers where you extend the `Controller` class a subclass of `ContainerAware` which contains the `getDoctrine()` method.

In other terms, this method works only on objects of class container or its subclasses, like this:  `$controller->getDoctrine()->getManager()`.

Besides, you don't want to have an EntityManager inside your entity classes, that's not a good way of doing things. You would better use listners to do such stuffs

Answer (score 1):

I solved this:

```
global $kernel;
$em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$role = $em->getRepository('BackendBundle:user_types')->findOneBy(array(
            'id'    => 10
        ));
```